# How to create html and its component class in ionic 2 /Angular 2 by using xml file

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
I want to create HTML elements by passing description in XML file for example
<component name='demoimg' type="image" src="add_bank_icon.png" theme="RegistrationInfo-img" />

then generate HTML page like

<img src='img/add_bank_icon.png' alt="demoimg" class='RegistrationInfo-img'/>
```

My question is how to generate HTML and its component class dynamically.

Comment: using `ng generate `  you can create pipe,component,Service,Class, etc 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: I would convert the XML into JSON, then iterate over it and place your HTML.

Comment: I want to create component and templates dynamically  by passing name in XML file like
<leafName='RegisterName'/>
and it should generate page registerName and its component class on runtime

Comment: I have converted to JSON, but my problem is how to create parent element on page if there is no any parent element